# How to clone the latest stable branch to a dir via github?

Tags: wordpress, git, github, installation

I want to clone the latest stable version of WordPress from Github, via a shell script. It is simple to get the unstable master branch:

```
git clone git://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git
```

But how can I get the highest numbered stable release *via a script*, not manually checking out the code. E.g., using deployment shell script or deployment tool such as Fabric.

Edit: I clarified the text to better indicate the intent that I meant how to do this from a script, not manually.

Comment: Please don't downvote this if the question seems specific to WordPress, it was migrated from wordpress.stackexchange.com and now it makes much less sense in context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I actually ended up doing, which is included in a [Fabric fabfile I have on Github](https://github.com/dangayle/nginx-wp-mysql-fabfile/blob/master/fabfile.py#L132):

```
git clone git://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git .
git checkout $(git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1))
```

It clones the repo like normal, then does some shell magic to find the latest tagged version of WordPress (Which is where the stable branches live.)

Answer (score 10):

Clone from git and change to the WordPress directory

```
git clone git://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git 
cd WordPress
```

Then list out the branches..

```
git branch -r
```

This gives something like...

```
origin/1.5-branch   
origin/2.0-branch   
...
origin/3.4-branch  
origin/HEAD -> origin/master   
origin/master
```

Check out the branch you want...

```
git checkout 3.4-branch
Branch 3.4-branch set up to track remote branch 3.4-branch from origin.
Switched to a new branch '3.4-branch'
```

Comment: Which version is in the master branch?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try a `git checkout master` ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this command after git clone

```
git checkout stable
```

Answer (score 0):

`git branch -r` will show you all the remote branches

`git checkout --track <local_branch> <remote>/<remote_branch>` will setup a local branch that is tracking the remote branch in order to push or get new updates.